# exporting next image from listbox

Tags: vb.net, image, listbox, export

I am trying to build an ImageConverter for my cousin (he needs that for his job) to export images in the following formats : 1. 2500x2500 , 2.1500x1500 and 3.800x800.

I only managed to export only one picture at a time in this formats , but he usually has over 50 pictures to convert in this formats daily , so I added a listbox so he can drag and drop his images in the listbox .I did managed that , but I don't know how to export the pictures that are loaded in the listbox , it needs to export one by one . The code I am using to export the images with "Export button" is here :

```
If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\" + KryptonTextBox1.Text)) Then
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\" + KryptonTextBox1.Text)

    Dim picturepath As String

    picturepath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\" + KryptonTextBox1.Text
    pathtxt.Text = picturepath
End If


Dim fileName As String = KryptonListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
Dim pathname As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

picturename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)
BildNametxt.Text = picturename

'converting picture in 2500x2500 format
Try
    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathtxt.Text + "\Amazon")) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathtxt.Text + "\Amazon")
    Else
        PictureBox2500.BackgroundImage.Save(pathtxt.Text + "\Amazon" + "\" + picturename + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)


    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try

Try
    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathtxt.Text + "\1500")) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathtxt.Text + "\1500")
    Else
        PictureBox1500.BackgroundImage.Save(pathtxt.Text + "\1500" + "\" + picturename + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try

Try

    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathtxt.Text + "\800")) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathtxt.Text + "\800")
    Else
        PictureBox800.BackgroundImage.Save(pathtxt.Text + "\800" + "\" + picturename + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try

MessageBox.Show("Images succesfully converted!")

resizedimage2500.Dispose()
resizedimage1500.Dispose()
resizedimage800.Dispose()
```

So how can I do the same thing with the loaded listbox ? Any help is apreciated ! Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly did you put in the listbox?

Comment: It loads the paths of the pictures that I need to convert

Comment: can anybody help me out please ?

Comment: If what you have works, move it to a method (Sub) and call it in a loop passing each filename as an argument